# I want to restrict access of my azure Kubernetes nginx ingress only for a particular location (api path) , only to be accessed from azure front door

Tags: kubernetes, nginx, azure-aks, nginx-ingress, azure-front-door

I want to restrict access of my azure Kubernetes nginx ingress only for a particular location (api path) , only to be accessed from azure front door.

I have a configuration snippet, but how to apply it to only a particular path

```
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: |
if ($http_x_azure_fdid !~* "xxxxx-xxx-xxx-xxxxxx")
{
return 403;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To restrict access of your Azure Kubernetes nginx ingress only for a particular location (api path), and only to be accessed from Azure Front Door, you can use the  `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet`  annotation in your ingress YAML file. The snippet you provided is a good start, but you need to modify it to apply only to a particular path. Azure Front Door doesn't automatically add an `X-Azure-FDID` header to requests. You will need to manually configure Azure Front Door to add a custom header to its requests if you want to use a custom header for filtering. Assuming you have configured Azure Front Door to add an `X-Azure-FDID` header to its requests, here is an example of how you can modify the snippet to apply only to the  `/api`  path:

```
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: |
  location /api {
    if ($http_x_azure_fdid !~* "xxxxx-xxx-xxx-xxxxxx") {
      return 403;
    }
  }
```

This snippet will only apply to requests that match the  `/api`  path. Requests to other paths will not be affected by this snippet.

Ingress:

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: frontdoor-ingress
  namespace: default
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: |
      if ($http_x_azure_fdid !~* "xxxxx-xxx-xxx-xxxxxx") {
        return 403;
      }
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
  - host: <yourcustomdomain.com>
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /api/restricted
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: your-service
            port:
              number: 80
```

[image]

References:

- [AKS NGINX controller](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/frontdoor/origin-security?pivots=front-door-standard-premium#public-ip-address-based-origins)